# How to attach needed claims to tokens with policy-based authorization?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, authorization

I am trying to implement policy-based authorization in my Web API. What I am trying to figure out is how to determine which claims should be added to the token when generating it for the user on his/her log-in operation. Should I store information about claims for each user in the database, or I am misunderstanding some concepts?

Here is the method I use to generate JWT/refresh-token pair:

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResponse> GenerateTokenPairForUserAsync(User user)
{
    var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtConfig.Secret);
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.RoleId.ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, guid)
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_jwtConfig.TokenLifetime),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
    };

    var token = jwtTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var jwtToken = jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    var refreshToken = new RefreshToken
    {
        JwtId = token.Id,
        IsUsed = false,
        IsRevoked = false,
        UserId = user.Id,
        CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
        ExpiryDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_refreshTokenConfig.TokenLifetime),
        Token = RandomString(25) + Guid.NewGuid()
    };

    await _refreshTokenRepository.CreateAsync(refreshToken);

    return new AuthenticationResponse
    {
        Token = jwtToken,
        Success = true,
        RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few things to achieve that:

- You should have a mapping of which clients can receive which claims. Clients, meaning the apps which call your authorization endpoint. If you only have one, then this is not a problem, but if you have many, you should keep somewhere in a database a list of all the claims that the given client should receive in the token.
- It's convenient to have a mapping of scopes to claims. In an authorization request you can then request scopes, which are essentially groups of claims. You will need that if your clients (or client) can actually request tokens with different scopes. E.g. you might want to request a token which can be used to perform some more sensitive operations, maybe change user's email. Then you can ask the server to issue the token maybe with a scope "admin", which translates to, among others, a claim `can_change_email: true`. This claim can then be used to perform authorization decisions.
- Finally you need to know, for every claim, what is the source of data. So, once you know that your tokens must contain claims `claim1`, `claim2` and `claim3`, then you must know where to take the data from. This can be hardcoded - e.g. you implement a `getValueForClaim2()` method which knows that it should read data from a database (e.g. it's a user's phone number). Or you can create some more sophisticated solutions, where you keep some mappings to claimProviders, then implement those providers. In the end, where do you get the data from it's totally up to you - this can be a database, a file, maybe an API call, or the value is calculated based on some input.

Have a look at these resources about claims that we wrote at Curity: https://curity.io/resources/claims/ if you want to learn more about this topic.